# Template class for Andrew's Monotone Chain Algorithm Convex Hull

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

This is my first attempt at writing a template class. I am implementing Andrew's Monotone Chain algorithm, as described [here](https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain) to calculate a 2D Convex Hull. Since this is my first try at templates, I would like a review of my code to make sure I get started on the right track.

**ConvexHull2d.h**

```
// ConvexHull2D
// Template class to calculate a 2D convex hull from a set of 2d points
// Uses Andrew's Monotone Chain Algorithm
// Algorithm based on code found at this web site:
// https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain
//
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace ConvexHull
{
  template <typename T>
  struct Point
  {
    T x, y;

    bool operator <(Point<T> const &p) const
    {
      return x < p.x || (x == p.x && y < p.y);
    }

    Point() :
      x(0),
      y(0)
    {
    }

    Point(T const tx, T const ty) :
      x(tx),
      y(ty)
    {
    }
  };

  typedef Point<int> PointInt;
  typedef Point<double> PointDouble;
  typedef std::vector<PointInt> PointIntArray;
  typedef std::vector<PointDouble> PointDoubleArray;

  template <typename T>
  T cross(Point<T> const &o, Point<T> const &a, Point<T> const &b)
  {
    return (a.x - o.x) * (b.y - o.y) - (a.y - o.y) * (b.x - o.x);
  }

  template <typename T>
  class ConvexHull2d
  {
  public:
    ConvexHull2d();
    ConvexHull2d(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in);
    ~ConvexHull2d();

    void InitHull(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in);
    std::vector<Point<T>> GetHullPoints() const;

  private:
    std::vector<Point<T>> m_inPoints;
    std::vector<Point<T>> m_hullPoints;
    void SetHullPoints(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in);
  };

  template <typename T>
  ConvexHull2d<T>::ConvexHull2d() :
    m_inPoints(),
    m_hullPoints()
  {
  }

  template <typename T>
  ConvexHull2d<T>::ConvexHull2d(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in)
  {
    InitHull(in);
  }

  template <typename T>
  ConvexHull2d<T>::~ConvexHull2d()
  {
  }

  template <typename T>
  void ConvexHull2d<T>::InitHull(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in)
  {
    m_inPoints = in;
    sort(m_inPoints.begin(), m_inPoints.end());
    SetHullPoints(m_inPoints);
  }

  template <typename T>
  void ConvexHull2d<T>::SetHullPoints(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in)
  {
    m_hullPoints.clear();
    int n = static_cast<int>(in.size()); //Total point count
    if (n < 3)
      return;
    int k = 0;
    m_hullPoints.resize(2 * n);
    // Build lower hull
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      while (k >= 2 && cross(m_hullPoints[k - 2], m_hullPoints[k - 1], in[i]) <= 0)
        k--;
      m_hullPoints[k++] = in[i];
    }
    // Build upper hull
    for (int i = n - 2, t = k + 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      while (k >= t && cross(m_hullPoints[k - 2], m_hullPoints[k - 1], in[i]) <= 0)
        k--;
      m_hullPoints[k++] = in[i];
    }
    m_hullPoints.resize(k-1); // This removes the last point added since it is the same as first point
  }

  template <typename T>
  std::vector<Point<T>> ConvexHull2d<T>::GetHullPoints() const
  {
    return m_hullPoints;
  }
}
```

Here is a program to test the class. It generates random integer and double points then calculates the convex hull.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "ConvexHull2d.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

double randomNumber(double mn, double mx);
int randomNumber(int mn, int mx);

using namespace ConvexHull;

int main()
{
  size_t const count = 100;
  int const minInt = -10;
  int const maxInt = 10;
  double const minDouble = -10.0;
  double const maxDouble = 10.0;

  std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));
  PointIntArray intPoints;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    int dx = randomNumber(minInt, maxInt);
    int dy = randomNumber(minInt, maxInt);
    intPoints.push_back(PointInt(dx, dy));
  }
  ConvexHull2d<int> intHull(intPoints);
  PointIntArray intHullPoints = intHull.GetHullPoints();

  PointDoubleArray doublePoints;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
  {
    double dx = randomNumber(minDouble, maxDouble);
    double dy = randomNumber(minDouble, maxDouble);
    doublePoints.push_back(PointDouble(dx, dy));
  }

  ConvexHull2d<double> doubleHull;
  doubleHull.InitHull(doublePoints);
  PointDoubleArray doubleHullPoints = doubleHull.GetHullPoints();

  std::cout << "Random doubles\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < doublePoints.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << doublePoints[i].x << ", " << doublePoints[i].y << std::endl;

  std::cout << "\nDouble Convex Hull points\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < doubleHullPoints.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << doubleHullPoints[i].x << ", " << doubleHullPoints[i].y << std::endl;

  std::cout << "\nRandom integers\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < intPoints.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << intPoints[i].x << ", " << intPoints[i].y << std::endl;

  std::cout << "\nInteger Convex Hull points\n";
  for (size_t i = 0; i < intHullPoints.size(); ++i)
    std::cout << intHullPoints[i].x << ", " << intHullPoints[i].y << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

double randomNumber(double mn, double mx)
{
   return mn + (static_cast<double>(std::rand()) / RAND_MAX) * (mx - mn);
}

int randomNumber(int mn, int mx)
{
  return mn + (static_cast<int>(std::rand()) % (mx - mn));
}
```

I am mainly interested in a review of my class, but any comments on the test program are welcome, as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SPOILER ALERT: you don't want a class at all; you want a function.

But first, the style nitpicks! :)

---

```
namespace ConvexHull
{
  void foo();
  ...
}
```

You'll find that a significant fraction of C++ programmers today "collapse" their namespaces like this:

```
namespace ConvexHull {

void foo();
...

} // namespace ConvexHull
```

It's a little bit "weird" to have an opening curly brace without indenting the following lines; but it's equally "weird" to have a (non-member) function definition that doesn't begin in column 1, and having to indent all your code past column 1 is *much* more painful to read and write. The benefits of "collapsed" style really start to show themselves with

```
namespace ConvexHull {
namespace detail {

...

} // namespace detail
} // namespace ConvexHull
```

or, as some would write it,

```
namespace ConvexHull { namespace detail {

...

} // namespace ConvexHull::detail
```

C++17 will probably support opening a multi-level namespace with `namespace ConvexHull::detail { }` directly.

---

Another "inconsistent" style preference that you'll see modern C++ programmers have moved toward is the placement of ampersands: `const Foo& x` instead of `const Foo &x`. The former is just easier to read, especially when you've got things like `T&& t` (versus `T &&t`). And yes, C++ programmers tend to agree with C programmers that it's correct to write `const int *p`, not `const int* p`. "Weird", yes, but it's all about readability.

---

It's strange that you spell the name of the class `ConvexHull2d`, but you don't spell the name of the helper class `Point2d` (it's just "`Point`"). What would you do if I wanted a `ConvexHull3d`?

You define typedefs for `PointInt`, `PointDouble`, `PointIntArray`, and `PointDoubleArray`, but then never use them. This is terribly bad style and you should get out of this habit.

- Why would the user ever *want* to use `PointInt`, when `Point<int>` is only two characters longer, and makes it much more clear what's going on?
- `PointIntArray` is not an array (neither a C-style array nor a `std::array`), so that's not even a good name for it.

---

```
void InitHull(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in);
```

What's up with this member function?  It seems like this method is provided *only* so that you can shove a new set of points into an existing `ConvexHull2d` object. But it doesn't really make sense to have a `ConvexHull2d` *without* a point-set; in fact you already provide a constructor

```
ConvexHull2d(std::vector<Point<T>> const &in);
```

(which by the way should be `explicit`). So if I'm ever tempted to write

```
ConvexHull2d empty;
empty.InitHull(somevector);
```

what I really *should* write is

```
ConvexHull2d empty(somevector);
```

And if I'm tempted to write

```
ConvexHull2d empty;
if (somecondition) {
    empty.InitHull(somevector);
} else {
    empty.InitHull(someothervector);
}
```

then what I *should* write is

```
ConvexHull2d empty;
if (somecondition) {
    empty = ConvexHull2d(somevector);
} else {
    empty = ConvexHull2d(someothervector);
}
```

There's no reason for the `InitHull` named method to exist. Use constructors and assignment operators for their designed purpose.

---

Relying on ADL to find `std::sort` is the bad kind of weird, and I'd say you shouldn't do it.

---

Your internal helpers `InitHull` and `SetHullPoints` aren't sufficiently differentiated to warrant two different entry points. Fortunately, we've just shown that `InitHull` is completely unnecessary. I'd argue that `SetHullPoints` is also unnecessary and should be inlined right into the constructor. That is:

```
template <typename T>
struct ConvexHull2d {
    ConvexHull2d() = default;

    explicit ConvexHull2d(const std::vector<Point<T>>& in)
        : m_inPoints(in)
    {
        std::sort(m_inPoints.begin(), m_inPoints.end());
        int n = in.size();
        if (n < 3) return;
        int k = 0;
        m_hullPoints.resize(2 * n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while (k >= 2 && cross(m_hullPoints[k - 2], m_hullPoints[k - 1], in[i]) <= 0) {
                k--;
            }
            m_hullPoints[k++] = in[i];
        }
        for (int i = n - 2, t = k + 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            while (k >= t && cross(m_hullPoints[k - 2], m_hullPoints[k - 1], in[i]) <= 0) {
                k--;
            }
            m_hullPoints[k++] = in[i];
        }
        m_hullPoints.resize(k-1);
    }

    std::vector<Point<T>> GetHullPoints() const {
        return m_hullPoints;
    }

private:
    std::vector<Point<T>> m_inPoints;
    std::vector<Point<T>> m_hullPoints;
};
```

Notice that I'm adhering to the [Rule of Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): the compiler-generated destructor is good enough for me, so I don't need to write it out explicitly. Similarly, I don't need to write out the body of the default constructor; I can just `=default` it. And I don't need to write a member-initializer for `m_hullPoints`; I can rely on the compiler to default-initialize that vector to the empty state.

I *do*, however, provide a default constructor, because without a default constructor you can't do some really useful things such as call `std::vector<ConvexHull2d>::resize()`.

---

Depending on how this class is going to be used in practice, you might prefer:

- to take `in` by value instead of by const-reference, and *move* it into `m_inPoints`
- to remove the member `m_inPoints` altogether, since it's never exposed to the user
- to have `GetHullPoints()` return a const-reference to `m_hullPoints`, instead of always returning a *copy* of `m_hullPoints` (for example if the caller just wants to iterate over it, not store or modify it)

---

It's a little strange to write `cross(o, a, b)` instead of `cross(a - o, b - o)` with a suitably overloaded `operator-(Point, Point)`. However, I could totally believe that `cross(o, a, b)` turns out to be faster for some reason, so maybe that strangeness is on purpose.

---

Are you planning to add any more members to the `ConvexHull2d` class? Because if not, I would strongly consider getting rid of the class altogether! Don't you just want a plain old function?

```
template<class Pt>
std::vector<Pt> GetHullPoints(std::vector<Pt> in)
{
    auto lex_less = [](const Pt& a, const Pt& b) { return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y); };
    std::sort(in.begin(), in.end(), lex_less);
    ...
    return hullPoints;
}
```

Not every abstraction in C++ requires a class — in fact, precious few do. If *all* you're doing here is transforming one pointset into a slightly sparser pointset, then that sounds like an excellent job for a *function*.

Also notice that by getting rid of the need to store the data long-term, I've been able to generalize my algorithm. Now instead of taking `Point<T>` for any `T`, it can actually operate on *any type `Pt` at all*, as long as a variable of type `Pt` has a member `.x` and a member `.y`.  This means that in my header that defines the `GetHullPoints` function, I don't need to define `class Point` at all; it's no longer part of my interface. Let the *user* worry about choosing the best representation for 2D points; all *I* care about is my algorithm for computing convex hulls!

For more about generalizing algorithms and separating the *algorithm* from the representation of the *data type*, I weakly recommend [Alexander Stepanov's lectures.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzvG9r05fTg) They're a bit long and digression-laden, but there's some good stuff in there.

---

So we started with "let's remove 2 spaces of indentation from every line in the file", passed through "let's remove two helper methods by inlining them", and finished up with "let's remove the entire class, along with all of `Point`"!  This is a common pattern in modern C++ programming — and actually in *all* programming. Eliminate all inessential complexity, and you'll find that what is left is the *essence* of the problem you're trying to solve. :)

Comment: Thank you for this review. I will study all the points you make and may have a few more questions. I do want to add methods to the class for object oriented bounding box, centroid and area. Should I still just use functions?

Comment: I learned a lot from this review. Your points are all well taken. However, there is one line of code you proposed that is still "magic"  to me: `auto lex_less = [](const Pt& a, const Pt& b) { return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y); };` I understand that it is defining a comparison function for `std::sort`, but I am having trouble understanding what exactly is going on. My best guess is it compares the first arguments, and returns result if not equal. If first parameters are equal, it then compares the second parameters. Is this correct?

Comment: If you're going to add more methods to the class that would benefit from sharing some of the data, then yes, a class is probably a good idea. At which point the interesting question becomes "how to keep from paying for the computation of bounding box, centroid, etc, if the user will never actually ask for them?" vs "how to avoid paying twice if the user asks twice?". As for the semantics of `std::tie`, first look up what `std::tie` does (it returns a `std::tuple`) and then look up the semantics of `operator<` on tuples. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp

Comment: Concerning the paying for the computations, what do you think about calculating when the get method is called then setting a bool variable?  The get method would check the status of the variable before the calculations and respond accordingly.